Automatically Choose another .NET-Version for Debugging an external application in Visual Studio
We have a DLL-Plugin using .NET-Framework 4.8.
For debugging we have to start the external application.

This Application seems to use .NET Core. When I start Debugging the following Dialog pops up

When attaching to the already running process I can choose the .NET-Version explicitly.

How can I tell my Project which .NET version it should choose for debugging when running automatically?

You could try to refer to the document Debug in mixed mode (C#, C++, Visual Basic)

Enable mixed-mode debugging for a managed calling app
Select the C# or
Visual Basic project in Solution Explorer and select the Properties
icon, press Alt+Enter, or right-click and choose Properties.
In Solution Explorer, select the C# or Visual Basic project node and
select the Properties icon, or right-click the project node and select
Properties.
Enable native code debugging in the properties.
For C#, select Debug in the left pane, select Open debug launch
profiles UI, then select the Enable native code debugging check box,
and then close the properties page to save the changes.

